# Oauth2 implicit flow

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, postman

I am trying to authenticate to an oauth2 provider with an implicit flow.

I am able to connect with postman and I am able to get a valid token. Can I see what postman do somewhere ?

[image]

However I cannot seem to find a library in javacript that can connect to an implicit flow.

I tried JSO and I keep getting an invalid_request error

```
let client = new jso.JSO(
{
  client_id: "redacted_",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:63342/untitled/index.html",
  authorization: "https://redacted_/connect/authorize",
  scopes: {
  request: ['apiclients']
},});
```

I also tried salte-auth but it seems that it only support a subset of providers.

How can I connect to the oauth2 provider like Postman did or how can I implement this in javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used Fiddler to compare Postman request to my request and I had to specify the response_type:

`response_type: 'token',`

Answer (score 0):

Postman just posts HTTP requests. You can see the HTTP requests in the Postman Console.
[image: Postman Console]

The Third button on the bottom left. With this you can see the difference between the requests you are making in JavaScript and Postman.